# How to make One Jquery script work for multiple inputs with slightly different name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jquery `keyup` script that changes a data-attribute for a `checkbox input` when a `text input` value is changed. Currently it works for only one instance of a `checkbox input` and `text input`. However, I need to modify the script to work for 10 instances.

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeef74/8jdfJ/9/) you can see that I have it working for the first instance number 1, but not for 2-10.

So for example, the script is triggered when a user changes the value of the input with the `id="account_balance1"` as seen below.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cost="100" debt="" value="" name="f_2[]"/>
```

This is the input where the value is entered for the keyup event

```
<input type="text" maxlength="7" class="balance" id="account_balance1" name="cardbalance" value=""/>
```

But I need it to work for 10 instances of these two inputs; for each instance there is an `li id=card_" and input id="account_balance_"` that increase 1 increment, like this... `li id="card_1"`  to  `li id="card_2"`  to  `li id="card_3"` and so on. This is same for the `input id="account_balance_1`, it goes to `_2`  to  `_3` and so on.

This is the keyup script

```
$(function () {
    $('#account_balance1').on('keyup blur paste', function() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            var str = $(self).val();
            $("input[data-cost][debt]").data('cost',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
            $("input[data-cost][debt]").data('debt',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
            $('#jquery-order-form').data('jprice').onChange();
        }, 0)
    })     
});
```

Comment: How about using a class? Then you could target by index.

Comment: Your could use data-* attributes as well as classes. Buts in your case I would use classes. It would work the fastest.

Comment: Hi michael, I answered your previous question. Working in the answer for this one ;)

Comment: Don't use custom attributes like `debt` -- all your user-defined attributes should begin with `data-`.

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado I was going to comment to you but I forgot. I tried but I kept getting errors

Comment: @Michael I added my answer, check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your jquery selector:

Instead of this:

```
$('#account_balance_1').on('keyup blur paste', function() {
```

do this:

```
$('.balance').on('keyup blur paste', function() {
```

This works because all your involved inputs have the class `balance`.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/8jdfJ/10/

Cheers

Comment: Since you answered the first one and understand how the script works. Maybe this is just a simple problem. But if you notice the blue total box to the right, it does not add them like it does it does in this example script http://preview.benmartinstudios.com.au/jquery-price-calculator-pro/quantities.html

Comment: Yep. I'll help you on that, too. But I anwered correctly both questions, you should mark them as accepted please ;)

Answer (score 0):

See this
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/
You just need to use this selector for selecting appropriate elements

```
 $('[id^=account_balance_').on('keyup blur paste', function() {...
```

Comment: Needs the closing bracket :)